# prevent dropdown area from opening of combobox control in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom combo box control in windows forms. I want to achieve a functionality wherein based on some condition the dropdown area should not be displayed i.e. I need to prevent the combo box from opening based on some condition.

I found a link where this can be achieved but it is completely preventing the dropdown area from showing. Also i am not able to tweak the method as per my convinience. The link is given [here](http://windowsclient.net/blogs/faqs/archive/2006/05/30/how-do-i-programmatically-prevent-the-combobox-drop-down-list-from-dropping-down.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add your condition to that `if` statement:

```
public class CustomComboBox : ComboBox
{
  protected override void WndProc( ref  Message m )
  {
    if(yourCondition && 
       (m.Msg == 0x201 || // WM_LBUTTONDOWN
        m.Msg == 0x203)) // WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK
      return;
    base.WndProc( ref m );
  }
}
```

Comment: What if the user opens it with the keyboard?